# Expo Client Not Getting Installed On Mac?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

The below command to install expo client in the official react native documentation fails.

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

The `error` shown is attached as a screenshot below.

[image]

Someone please tell me how to solve this the `github` issue below they are pointing to has no answers for this.

https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

its like if someone new tries to develop on `expo` its not possible ??

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning and there are plenty in the React Native ecosystem.

What do you mean by:

> its like if someone new tries to develop on expo its not possible ??

1. Using `expo` client to work on your own React Native application

or

2. Developing features/fix for the `expo` sdk?

---

It's working on my machine

```
❯ expo --version
3.15.4
```

Comment: when we install expo using npm install -g expo-cli
first the command line stucks and points to the github issue if someone doesn't wait he will never figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

But looks like if you wait for some time the installation of `expo client` continues even though at first it looks stuck and points to a `github` issue.

But why that delay and confusion in a widely used `platform` it should be avoided.